# Hitting a different Struts action with DisplayTag Pagination

Tags: struts, displaytag

I'm trying to implement displaytag pagination with a little different funcitonality. Basically, I have 3 displaytag tables on my jsp, and when the user wishes to see the next set of results on one of them it brings them to a new resultant jsp which only displays the info from the table they wished to paginate.

This should be relatively simple to do. However when the user clicks a pagination link, displayTag hits the ORIGINAL struts action that it used in displaying the original data. I want to be able to hit a new struts action.

I don't think I've explained that terribly well so heres a little example.

1. User does a search.
2. A struts action called 'searchAllTypes' is hit and returns a jsp.
3. Results for 3 different types (x,y and z) are displayed in 3 seperate tables.
4. User wishes to see the next 10 results for table y so clicks 'next' on y's table.
5. A struts action called 'searchYType' is hit and returns a new jsp.

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this.

-gearoid.

**EDIT:** I really want to hit a different **method** inside my Struts Action - should have clarified that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Will setting the requestURI attribute for each table tag help?

http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/10/tagreference-displaytag-12.html#table

http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/faq.html#action

Comment: It would seems as though I can hit a new Struts action but not a new method. For example, if I first hit a method called searchAllTypes then this method is constantly being hit for pagination despite changing the RequestURI....

Any help very much appreciated.